# 403/405 status code Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Link to redirect the users into our app and using the Google-provided domains (`https://example.page.link`) for the URL prefix. The link works fine for most people but sometimes some users might encountered with these issues:

[image: 405 response] [image: 403 response]

Does anyone know what might cause this issue? I'm not sure how to reproduce these issues. Sometimes it will works after the user retry for multiple attempts.

Ps: It's a Flutter app. I've contacted Firebase support and they asked for minimal repro which I'm not sure how to create because it rarely happens but quite frequent.

Comment: Did you try changing the domain to a more specific one? Does it fails on Android, on iOS or both? The images are not readable.

Comment: Apologies, my bad, i've uploaded the new images. It failed for both platform Android and iOS @MicheleVolpato. I haven't tried to change the domain though

Comment: Are the failing links different from the non failing ones? Or does it fail on the same links? You might be doing something weird on creation of the links, with some weird characters.

You need to create your own free subdomain (`something.page.link`) in the Firebase console. Do not use `https://example.page.link`.

Comment: @MicheleVolpato the links are different from the others as it carries unique token in the query parameter. The link is just an example. I've created my own subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reason For this :

**How many dynamic links can be created in firebase?**

> The quota is listed in the Dynamic Links documentation: Requests are
> limited to 50 queries per second 5 requests/IP address/second, and
> 100,000 200,000 queries per day. If exceeded, then the response will
> return HTTP error code 429/403/405.

Comment: From https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest, bottom of the page.

"Requests are limited to 5 requests/IP address/second, and 200,000 requests/day. If exceeded, then the response will return HTTP error code 429."

The error received was 405